# .htaccess RewriteRule help

Tags: .htaccess

I have been able to change the 'location' of my images with RewriteRule, but I have 3 lines of code to do this because of subdirectories in the image folders

```
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+).(jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif|png)$ /includes/images/$1.$2
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/([^/]+).(jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif|png)$ /includes/images/$1/$2.$3
RewriteRule ^images/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+).(jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif|png)$ /includes/images/$1/$2/$3.$4
```

However, I would like to be able to not need to add to these if I ever add any deeper subdirectories.

I have tried many different approaches to this with no luck, and the following is what I am stuck with atm.

```
RewriteRule ^(images)(/?[^/])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.bmp|.gif|.png)$ /includes/$&
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this code to work??

Also, is there any way to view the URL that is being used server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see any reason that you couldn't simply do:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)\.(jpg|jpeg|bmp|gif|png)$ /includes/images/$1.$2
```